# Updating AssemblyInfo.cs for multiple projects in a solution for adding a version numbers

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Is there a tool to update the assembly version in AssemblyInfo.cs for all projects in a solution?
I have a solution which has about 30+ projects and I don't see myself checking out AssemblyInfo.cs for each of these projects from source control(TFS) and doing this manually.
Basically I'm looking for something that will remove
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")] and change 
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")] to [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]

I could set the source control plugin settings to automatically check out instead of prompting but still need to have AssemblyInfo update automatically somehow.

Answer (score 1):

I always do that during the Build. See http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/05/13/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-5-Increase-AssemblyVersion.aspx for detailed steps

Comment: This is really useful. Does it make sense to have the version numbers increment for local builds or does it make sense to have this happen only on the build machine running the TFS build agent

Comment: I would vote to only do it on the build machine. There are so many local builds and I did not ever had the requirement to change the version number in a local build. But I don't know your situation.